# Magento 2 navigation menu

Tags: magento, magento2

I'm very new to Magento 2 framework. I have a total of 14 top-level categories in my site but it's showing only first 10 categories in frontend menu navigation only. I tried to set Category Top Navigation = 0(Maximal Depth). But it doesn't effect on the frontend. Can you guys please help me to overcome this problem?

Comment: I'm using Magento 2

Comment: Please put a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example in the question itself.